Proof that f is injective $\Leftrightarrow$ for $M_1,M_2 \subset M$ :$f(M_1)\cap f(M_2)=f(M_1 \cap M_2)$
Let $f:M \rightarrow N$. Then f is injective $\Leftrightarrow$ for $M_1,M_2\subset M:f(M_1)\cap f(M_2)=f(M_1\cap M_2)$.
Proof:
$\leftarrow$
Without loss of generality $M_1$ and $M_2$ are disjunct. Then the equation yields: $f(M_1\cap M_2)=\emptyset = f(M_1)\cap f(M_2)$. This shows infectivity of f.
$\rightarrow$
We know that f is injective. Choose $y\in f(M_1)\cap f(M_2)$. Because f is injective this implies the that $M_1$ and $M_2$ aren't disjunct and have a common element $a$.
Thus we have: $f(M_1\cap M_2)=f(a)=y=f(M_1)\cap f(M_2)$
and we are done.
Question: I'm not sure about my $\leftarrow$ step. Could someone maybe point out if I'm right?
Edit: I want to point out for future visitors that this proof is completely wrong.

Both are wrong. In $\rightarrow$, $f(M_1\cap M_2)$ is not a number. It is a set.

$(\Longleftarrow)$ If $M$ has one element, then we are done.
Suppose that there are at least two elements in $M$, then we can choose two different elements $x_1,x_2\in M$. Since $\{x_1\}\subseteq M$ and $\{x_2\}\subseteq M$, set $M_1=\{x_1\}, M_2=\{x_2\}$, then $f(M_1)\cap f(M_2)=f(M_1\cap M_2)=\varnothing$,i.e., $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$. Since this holds for arbitrary $x_1,x_2\in M$, we are done.
$(\Longrightarrow)$
It is obvious that $f(M_1\cap M_2)\subseteq f(M_1)\cap f(M_2)$ since for any $y\in f(M_1\cap M_2)$, there exists $x_1\in M_1\cap M_2$ such that $f(x_1)=y$, which implies that $y=f(x_1)\in  f(M_1)$ and $f=f(x_1)\in f(M_2)$. One the other hand, if $y\in f(M_1\cap M_2)$, then there exists $x_1\in M_1, x_2\in M_2$ such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=y$. Since $f$ is injective, $x_1=x_2\in M_1\cap M_2$ and thus $y=f(x_1)=f(x_2)\in f(M_1\cap M_2)$.
